# JS program with no err is not running on vs code and when i upload it to git,empty file is getting uploaded to git although i have written code in it

Tags: javascript, git, github, visual-studio-code

This is my js code , it works fine when i checked on online compiler but it's not showing any output on vs code i tried reinstalling nodejs,but still it's not showing console.log() output.And when i try to upload it on git,it uploads gets uploaded without any error but when i check it on my repo the file is empty.
It's not showing any output although i have written console.log and when i upload this file to github it becomes empty file.
I'm newbie,please ignore if i mispronounced any terms.

````
  let d=cash-price,m,l;
  let cur=[0.01,0.05,0.1,0.25,1,5,10,20,100];
  let x=cur.reduce((prev,curr)=>{return Math.abs(curr-d)<Math.abs(prev-d) && curr<d?curr:prev});
  let index=cur.indexOf(x);
  let sum=cid.slice(0,index+1)
             .map(curr=>curr[1])
             .reduce((prev,curr)=> prev+curr);
 
//first case open:-           
  let open=[];           
  console.log();
  if((sum-d)>0){
      if(cid[index][1]/cur[index] >= d/cur[index]){
        cid[index][1]=d;
        d=0;
        return {status:"OPEN",change:[cid[index]]}
      }
      else if(cid[index][1]/cur[index] < d/cur[index]){
        for(let i=index;i>=0;i--){
          l=cid[i][1]/cur[i];
          m=d/cur[i];
          if(l<m){
            cid[i][1]=Math.floor(l)*cur[i];
            open.push(cid[i]);
            d=d-cid[i][1];
          }
          else if(m<l)
           { 
             cid[i][1]=Math.floor(m)*cur[i];
              open.push(cid[i]);
              d=d-cid[i][1];
           }
          }
    }
    for(let i=0;i<open.length;i++){
      if(open[i][1]==0){
        open.splice(i,1);
        open[i][1]+=cur[open.length-i-1];
      }
    }
    return {status:"OPEN",change:open};
  }
  
//second case insufficient balance:-
if((sum-d)<0){
    return {status:"INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS",change:[]};
}

//third case closed:-
let total=cid.map(curr=>curr[1])
             .reduce((prev,curr)=> prev+curr);
if(total-d==0){
    return {status:"CLOSED",change:cid};
  }
}

console.log(checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]])); ```
````

Comment: i suggest dividing your question into 2 question ... one is why the code is not running and the other is the github problem and don't forget to descrip how you are uploading this file to github

Comment: Are you sure that the file you edit is the same as the file you run and push? Where do you test? Do you test locally, or after deploying? What do you see in previous commits? Run `git log`, see some hashes there and then run `git show <the hash>`. Tell us the result.